# unhandled exceptions at startup in my c# project

Tags: c#, exception, botframework, unhandled-exception

I am getting below Unhandled exception at the startup of my chatbot application in output window.

```
Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Security.SecurityException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.BadImageFormatException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentNullException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
```

I have something in my MessageController

```
public class MessagesController : ApiController
    {
        private static NLog.Logger logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        private static DocumentClient client;
        // Retrieve the desired database id (name) from the configuration file
        private static readonly string databaseId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseId"];
        // Retrieve the desired collection id (name) from the configuration file
        private static readonly string collectionId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CollectionId"];
        // Retrieve the DocumentDB URI from the configuration file
        private static readonly string endpointUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EndpointUri"];
        // Retrieve the DocumentDB Authorization Key from the configuration file
        private static readonly string authorizationKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PrimaryKey"];

        /// <summary>
        /// POST: api/Messages
        /// Receive a message from a user and reply to it
        /// </summary>
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation($"Type={activity.Type} Text={activity.Text}");

            //disable the Application Insights and DocumentDb logging in local enviornment
            #if (LOCAL)            
                Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration.Active.DisableTelemetry = true;
            #endif
            #if (!LOCAL)
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(endpointUrl) &&  !String.IsNullOrEmpty(authorizationKey))
                { 
                    using (client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpointUrl), authorizationKey))
                    {
                        await CaptureConversationData(activity);
                    }
                }
            #endif

            if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
            {
                //await Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new ContactOneDialog());

                //Implementation of typing indication
                //ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new System.Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
                //Activity isTypingReply = activity.CreateReply("Shuttlebot is typing...");
                //isTypingReply.Type = ActivityTypes.Typing;
                //await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(isTypingReply);

                logger.Debug("The User's local timeStamp is: " + activity.LocalTimestamp + "and service timeStamp is: " + activity.Timestamp);
                await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () =>
                new ExceptionHandlerDialog<object>(new ShuttleBusDialog(), displayException: true));
            }
            else
            {
                HandleSystemMessage(activity);
            }
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
            return response;
        }
}
```

It thrown at first line

```
private static NLog.Logger logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

here is the snapshot[image: Exceptione], [image: exception2]

One weired thing is that if my project run from C:\Users\\chatbot\Mybot..
then these exception are not getting thrown even i have put the break exception setting in exception setting window.
but if I move the project to c:\Sandy\MyStuff\ChatbOt\MyBot it's started throwing all these exception since i have put the break exception setting in exception setting window.

I am seriously not able to understand what is the problem.

Comment: I think it may be due to your References to the dlls mentioned. Make sure you have "copy local" set to true for those dlls and rebuild it once after moving to the new folder.

Comment: Try use MSDN, just type in google your exception and follow the link. All errors are described there. `FileNotFound` - because some files not found. `ArgumentNull` - because in that line some arguments are null (check App.Config is contains all configs that you use in code). `BadImageFormat` - means that one of dll/exe files on witch you have reference possible was compilled with other framework version, and you use latest version in project.

Comment: And about "Moved to another folder". Check all paths in project references. Especially with static paths, make shure that they are exist at this path.

Comment: @sergio, let me try what you explained . I will update you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try running your visual studio as administrator or running your application as administrator, and check that all the Dlls that your project depends on are there in the new path.

Comment: running visual studio as administrator works fine , i tried previously but just wanted to know the actual issue.

Comment: I think maybe its because that the path "C:\" have different permissions than  "C:\Users"